# How to insert content of a file at the top of all files in a directory?

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script that recursively insert the copy right header into all the files inside the directory. However, I don't want to insert the copyright header to this script itself. How can I do that? My script is below.

The second thing I want to do is to insert this only in specific file type. E.g., *.java , *.c, etc.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *;
do
  if [$file == $0];
  then
    continue
  fi
  echo "copyright 
 "> copyright-file.txt;
  echo "" >> copyright-file.txt;
  cat $file >> copyright-file.txt;
  mv copyright-file.txt $file;
done
```

Comment: I assume, the low-tech solution `mv script ..` is out of question?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

copyright_file="copyright-file.txt"
cat > "$copyright_file" << EOF
copyright

EOF
for file in *; do
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue                   # only regular files
  [[ "$file" = "$copyright_file" ]] && continue  # skip copyright file
  [[ "$file" = "$0" ]] && continue               # skip the script
  cat - "$file" < "$copyright_file" > "$file.new" && mv "$file.new" "$file"
done
```

- `cat - "$file" < "$copyright_file"` - reads copyright file from stdin first, then the file itself

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You may want to check the file for an existing copyright before appending/prepending a new copyright.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#
# Directory where this script is located
#
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

#
# Save the name of the script in a global env variable
#
SCRIPT_NAME="$(basename $0)"

#
# Create copyright file
#
declare cr_file="${DIR}/copyright-file.txt"
echo "copyright data" > "${cr_file}"

#
# Get a list of java and c files
#
declare files=$(find "${DIR}" -regex ".*\.\(java\|c\)")

#
# Loop through files found and append header
#
for file in ${files[@]}; do
    # Skip file if it's this script.
    # Note this file will never be encountered, using the regex above, but
    # this is how to skip it.
    if [[ "${file}" == "${DIR}/${SCRIPT_NAME}" ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Prepend as header
    echo -e "$(cat "${cr_file}")\n$(cat ${file})" > "${file}"

    # -OR- Append as footer
    echo "$(cat "${cr_file}")" >> "${file}"
done
```